# Calculate quantity made from bill of materials

Tags: sql, stock

I am trying to calculate the quantity of product picked based on a bill of materials. I have managed to make it work with a loop but its messy and slow and i'm sure there must be a way to do it with an SQL query.
I have two tables. 1 contains the BOM so it has parent stock code and all child stock code + bom qty's for each bom.
The second table contains the order quantity and the quantity picked, for example.
ABOM contains Item1 and item2 each have a bom qty of 1.

An order is placed for 2 x ABOM so my program adds the bom children to the order. So i have 2 lines:
Item1 requires 2 to be picked
Item2 required 2 to be picked

In this example is Item 1 has 2 picked but item 2 only has 1 picked i want to update the quantity picked for ABOM to 1.
Is it possible to achieve this with a query that always returns the correct picked quantity for the parent stock code based on the order / picked quantities of the children?

Many thanks in advance for any help available :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "sql" databases have significant variations in language syntax. So for best results use a tag that identifies which db you are using (e.g. MySQL, Oracle, Postgres).  Plus;  [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)